# What are differences between WMS, WFS, WCS, WPS?

Tags: wms, wfs, wps, wcs

By looking at [image]

I do not understand the differences between WMS, WFS, WCS, and WPS.

Can you explain the differences between them?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**[Overview: WMS, WFS, WCS](https://web.archive.org/web/20230320102912/http://www.winwaed.com/blog/2009/02/09/overview-wms-wfs-wcs/)** describes the differences between WMS, WFS, and WCS fairly clearly.

> WMS is probably the best known of these three standards due to its widespread use by map servers to deliver map images.

---

> In contrast to the images served by WMS, WFS communicates geographic feature information.
>
> The WFS web service allows features to be queried, updated, created, or deleted by the client.

---

> The WCS web service is used to transfer "coverages", ie. objects covering a geographical area.
>
> Coverages can be a set of data points; a regular grid of points (or pixels); a set of segmented curves (eg. road paths); a set of Thiessen polygons; or a TIN triangulated irregular network (eg. terrain models).

Wikipedia has articles on **[WMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service)**, **[WFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service)**, **[WCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Coverage_Service)**, **[WMTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Tile_Service)** and **[WPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Processing_Service)**.

If you want to view the specifications on all of these, you can visit the OGC websites and download the pdfs.

- **[WMS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms)**
- **[WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs)**
- **[WCS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wcs)**
- **[WMTS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts)**
- **[WPS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wps)**
- **[WCPS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wcps)**