# Adding raster layer in GeoServer using ArcPy gives exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)?

Tags: arcpy, wms, weighted-overlay

I am trying to perform a weighted overlay analysis using ArcPy. As input I'm using 5 map layers of same column and heights.

```
def weightOverlay():
  ambu = "rasterambu1.tif"
  fire = "rasterfire1.tif"
  hosp = "rasterhosp1.tif"
  markets = "rastermarkets1.tif"
  schools = "rasterschools1.tif"
```

In this way i retrieved raster layers stored in local starage(Hard disk).
Final map generated without any issues.

Then I uploaded same layers to the geoserver and tried to retrieve data as a wms.

```
ambu = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/research/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=research:ServiceAmbulance&styles=&bbox=79.8404565168211,6.862710007340316,79.89034870025498,6.980707309511519&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Ftiff8"
fire = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/research/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=research:ServiceFireRescue&styles=&bbox=79.8404565168211,6.862710007340316,79.8903487011599,6.980707309511519&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Ftiff8"
hosp = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/research/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=research:Hospitals&styles=&bbox=79.85332108963203,6.870961918700771,79.8883085657193,6.958916057188321&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Ftiff8"
markets = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/research/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=research:Servicemarkets&styles=&bbox=79.8404565213477,6.862887697616292,79.8903487056314,6.980707309511519&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Ftiff8"
schools = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/research/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=research:ServiceSchool&styles=&bbox=79.84045652315942,6.862887697616292,79.89034870025498,6.980707309511519&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Ftiff8"
```

But this time It gives the following error

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

How can I get layers from GeoServer as an input for the weighted overlay analysis?

Comment: A WMS is just a cartographic representation of your data - i.e. a georeferenced image. You would need a WCS. See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80948/what-are-the-differences-between-wms-wfs-wcs-wps) for a discussion of this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a GeoServer issue, or more of one to do with ArcPy.  Can you check if the GeoServer receives the requests, if so what HTTP status code is returned.

Comment: @nmtoken can you please mention how to check whether GeoServer receives the requests

Comment: The `geoserver.log` will, I think, show the requests.  If you're using Tomcat, then you should also check the localhost_access_logs.   You should also be able to sniff out the requests sent by your application using something like Fiddler or Wireshark.