# QGIS WMS tooltip displaying web address from data

Tags: qgis, wms, tooltip

I am using BGS WMS borehole data in QGIS:

https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/GeoIndex_Onshore/boreholes/MapServer/WmsServer

I'm trying to get a tooltip to come up displaying the URL from the attributes for each point.

How can I do it or are there any other options for getting the point to open a URL in the default web browser when clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least that's not how WMS is meant to work. You likely want WFS. There are a few questions about the differences: [What are the differences between WMS, WFS, WCS, WPS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80948/what-are-the-differences-between-wms-wfs-wcs-wps)

Short version: **WMS** is a *pre-rendered map* - you never have the raw data locally. While you can get information about the underlying features via a GetFeatureInfo request, that's usually done by clicking on a feature, not simply mousing-over.

**WFS** is for the *raw vector data*. In that case you have the points locally and you can do what you like with them including setting up tooltips (whether *that* is possible, and how to do it I leave for someone else).

Unfortunately for you, the BGS Borehole data seems to be WMS only:
https://www.geoseer.net/s.php?q=bgs+borehole

Comment: A GetFeatureInfo-Request can display attributes in WMS. In QGIS try to use the "Info tool", which sends this request.